# Qt Creator, build dir with branch name

Tags: c++, git, qt, qt-creator

Based on several kits I am using, the Qt Creator build directory is derived from

- project name
- Qt version
- compiler
- build configuration: debug / release

Example: `build-client-Qt_5_3_0_fooProject_MINGW_32bit_qmake_MinGW22-Debug`

My problem is, if I switch my git branch, I always have to recompile from scratch (time consuming). I wonder, if it might be possible to include the branch name, so I can keep different builds at the same time

=> Possible build dirs:

- `build-client-Qt_5_3_0_fooProject_MINGW_32bit_qmake_MinGW22-Debug_master`
- `build-client-Qt_5_3_0_fooProject_MINGW_32bit_qmake_MinGW22-Debug_branchbar`

Or is there a chance to add a third build configuration, e.g. `Debug_others`, resulting in a build directory such as

`build-client-Qt_5_3_0_fooProject_MINGW_32bit_qmake_MinGW22-Debug_others`

Comment: When you checkout your git branch, you change existing files and therefore it triggers rebuilding them. You may consider keep several build directories - one per branch.

Comment: Sorry, do not get your comment. This is what I am asking for, how can I manage different build dirs automatically, e.g. based on the branch name.

Answer (score 3):

You can manage builds in `Project` tab on the left. If you want to have build automaticaly switching dirs depending on the branch you are on, on each branch you would have to edit `*.pro.user` file. Find line:

```
<value type="QString" key="ProjectExplorer.BuildConfiguration.BuildDirectory">
    /home/etc/etc/etc
</value>
```

And change the directory to the one you want it to be (ex. edit the ending part of the value). On a different branch have it point somewhere else. Thus changing branches will change the shadow build directory.

P.S. If you have several builds (like debug, release) you need to check if the build directory you're editing is the one you want. Check `activeBuildConfiguration` number and edit it's directory only (the number of build is usually a line above the one I showed), or change `activeBuildConfiguration` to 0 and the first build directory.

It's a bit knotty but I think manageable.

Comment: A little hacky indeed but I would still consider it a good solution. The problem is, though, that at least in my case the *.pro.user file is ignored by git (which makes sense as it is literally user-specific), so switching branches cannot change the config in this file.

Comment: Multi-User extension: Copy your myproj.pro file to myproj-USERNAME.pro (or make them include a .pri with the content). Then every developer can check in their  myproj-USERNAME.pro.user file and change it in every branch.